# Section Overflowing the Slider - CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I was trying to figure it out how can I fix the CSS of the slider and the first section.

As you can see the 1st section w/c should have a background of white is a scrolling as well with the background of the slider which is should not be the case.

So I tried the ff codes using the inspector element of chrome to check if that will fix the issue:

```
.carousel-inner .item.content_vertical_middle .slider_content_outer{
  display: block;
}

.vc_column_container{
  background: #fff;
}
```

However it doesn't solve the problem. Anyone can identify w/c CSS should exactly should I use here? Feel free to visit the dev site and use inspector tool?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the full code so that we can identify the issue.

Comment: Please add all of your code, and maybe a more in-depth explanation of what should be happening

Comment: Hi DKyleo, you can visit the site I put above. If you scroll down you'll see that the first section the text " EVER EASY SHIPPING WITH COSHIPPER" is being scrolled as well with slider's background. By default I place some white background on this but it seems it's also scrolling. Feel free to use inspector tools.

Comment: _“Feel free to use inspector tools”_ - oh how mighty gracious of you :-) But please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if i understand you correctly, the white background that is on the element with the text "EVER EASY SHIPPING" should be visible straight away on scroll instead of popping up late yes?

If so it seems to be a layering issue. I added this CSS to solve it:

```
div.section {
    position: relative; /* already on element */
    z-index: 999999; /* my addition */
}
```

Its just inside .full_width .full_width_inner. Hope this helps!

Note: the z-index may not have to be as high as 99, i just did that to make sure it was high enough to work!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to use the inspector tools of chrome while visiting your site and it seems that the slider is also scrolling the 1st element with the "Ever easy shipping" section w/c I believe should be a block element and must scrolled with a white background.

In line with that I tried to check it on Chrome inspector tool...try the following:

```
.parallax_content.center, .parallax_content_full_width.center {
    display: block;
}


section.parallax_section_holder{
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: jon dobie thanks for the answer yeah when I scroll on the slider it's also scroilling the first element with the slider background. It should be scrolled with the white background. Unfortunately I tried your solution but did not work.